# Error message: "setw is not defined" using g++

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile using gcc a project which earlier used SunStudio and am getting an error in the following code:

```
ostream & operator << ( ostream & os, const UtlDuration & d )
{
    if ( d._nsec == 0 )
    {
        os << d._sec << " sec";
        return os;
    }
    else
    {
        cout.fill( '0' );
                os << d._sec << "." << std::setw(9) << d._nsec << " sec";
        cout.fill( ' ' );
        return os;
    }
}
```

Error: “setw” is not a member of “std”

I am not able to resolve this error can someone please explain me reason behind this error

Comment: did you include <iomanip>?

Comment: Yes that's correct <iomanip> was included but got excluded as I didn't defined some required macros.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You need to include the header which declares it:

```
#include <iomanip>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do following two steps:

1. include iomanip
2. write std::setw() instead of setw()

Compile and enjoy...

Answer (score -1):

setw(num) is not defined in iostream library. So add-

```
#include <iomanip>
```

in the code
and add

```
using namespace std
```

it worked for me.

Comment: `using namespace std` is unnecessary if you use `std::setw` (as OP does), and is often  [considreded bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2752075).

Comment: yes you don't need to add the std namespace twice. either you define it with setw as-(std:: setw) or you can mention it by -(using namespace std;). One should not use both.