# How to write the content of an array into a text file?

Tags: c++, arrays, logging

How to write the content of an array to a text file?
Is it possible?

Below is my code:

```
x=0;
y=0;
//copy to real array
if(nRow == 0){
    for(i=nTCol; i>=0 ; i--){
        nPanelMap[nRow][x] = nTempMap[i];
        x++;
    }

}
if(nRow == 1){
    for (i=nTCol; i>=0 ; i--){
        nPanelMap[nRow][y] = nTempMap[i];
        y++;
    }
}
k=0;

for (i=nTCol; i>=0 ; i--){
    array [k] = nPanelMap[nRow][x];
    k++;
    array [k] = nPanelMap[nRow][y];
    k++;

}
j=0;
for (i=nTCol; i>=0 ; i--){

    nPanelMap[nRow][j] = array [k];
    j++;
}
nRow++;
```

I would like to print out arrays `x`, `y`, `k`, and `j` and write them into a text file.
The purpose of doing this is to ensure that the data passing is correct.

Comment: Well for writing to a text file, [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) is a good tutorial/synopsis in regards to C++ Use <iomanip> for formatted output to make it look neat, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226143/formatting-output-in-c) answer for an example.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can write into a text file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  const int size = 5;
  double x[] = {1,2,3,4,5}; 

  ofstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    myfile << "This is a line.\n";
    myfile << "This is another line.\n";
    for(int count = 0; count < size; count ++){
        myfile << x[count] << " " ;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
  return 0;
}
```

**More reference:** http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

To write array data use this.

```
for(int count = 0; count < size; count ++){
            out_myfile << x[count] << " " ;
}
```

Comment: how to write the content of the array into the text file?

Comment: so, you never define `out_myfile`.  i'm guessing this is supposed to be `myfile`?  also, is `a` supposed to be `count`?

Comment: @dbliss ok define it, but x is for assume array.

Comment: is the write buffered? Or written byte by byte?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that you use the JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) format if you want the resulting file to be human readable. JSON is documented at http://json.org/. The ThorsSerializer found at https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer is a C++ Serialization library for JSON. Serialization, as defined at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization, "is the process of translating data structures or object state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link) and reconstructed later in the same or another computer environment." If ThorsSerializer does not work for you, I suggest that you do a Google search for "C++ JSON Serialization library."

Another option I found when doing this Google search is "cereal - A C++11 library for serialization" found at http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/.

Comment: Using JSON should be considered when saving and loading arrays in an application but it is IMHO an overkill for dumping arrays for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Use fstream class for operations like file write, read, append, seek, etc..